# Teamcity Project build from sub folder - checkout rules "unsupported"

Tags: npm, teamcity

I have a repo with a structure as:

repo\src\folder1\project1

repo\src\folder1\project2

I've updated the checkout rules to be: `+:src/folder1/project1 => .`
But when the npm commands in the build step are run (I've also added build to the below) I can see in the build log that the checkout rule isn't applied:

[image]

I used the UI in the checkout rules to select the appropriate folder where this project resides, but the error message isn't at all clear. What is wrong with the checkout rule? How do I build at a given path?

Build steps:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's just not supported with Git:

> Limitations When using checkout on an agent, a limited subset of
> checkout rules is supported, because Git cannot clone a subdirectory
> of a repository. You can only map the whole repository to a specific
> directory using the following checkout rule +:.=>subdir. The rest of
> the checkout rules are not supported.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Git#Git-Limitations

Which makes the checkout rules mainly useless it seems.
I'm guessing this will have to be done in the build steps if that is possible.

However, as an alternative the `Build Step` can be modified via the `Working directory` parameter to target the build at a specific path, which worked for me.